# AWS Cognito is sending a phone verification text when the email verification link is clicked?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

In our application, when a user signs up they get a one time verification email with a link that they click to confirm the email (VERIFY YOUR EMAIL BY CLICKING THIS LINK).  This then usually sends a confirmation email, but instead seems to also send the user a phone SMS message with a phone verification code when the link is clicked (Your verification code is: XXXXX).  For context this text is supposed to be sent (and is also sent) when the user signs in.  It seems Cognito is getting its steps mixed up, has anyone ran into this before?  Any help would be amazing.  Thank you!

PS.  We are using Node.js for the lambda functions.  We use a pre signup lambda, a post confirmation lambda and a post auth lambda that logs information.

This problem first appeared when needing to re-register our toll free number when texts started failing to go through during our registration process.  We then waited for the number to get through the vetting process and afterwards the double text issue was still occurring.

The next thing we tried doing was removing all code from the situation (lambda triggers on the user pool) and run the sign in/sign up process.  We thought that since in the post confirmation lambda there was code sending the SES email for email verification something may be wrong there.  When removing all the triggers and hitting the default email link verification it still sent an SMS.

Lastly, we then tried making a whole separate user pool with the same configuration and no users/ with imported users. Cognito still sent a text (Your verification code is: XXXXX) to the user's phone after they hit the VERIFY YOUR EMAIL HERE link.